# How to have a specific function break free from the setInterval loop>

Tags: javascript, setinterval

I have the following code with a setInterval() method. However there is one function in between i.e **audio.play()**. Whenever setInterval is called the whole function is called again and so the audio plays again and again. Is there any way of run the setInterval() method but have an exception for the audio.play part?
Here is the code

```
setInterval(async () => {
    //api stuff
    const detections = await faceapi
      .detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions());
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);
    const happy  =resizedDetections[0].expressions.happy;

    //The Issue  starts from here
    if(happy>0.9)
    {
      audio.src="audios/happy_audio.wav";
      audio.play();
    }

    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections);
  },1000)
})
```

Comment: why don't you move the code out of the setInterval(), so that it's executed only once?

Comment: `setInterval` doesn't just run code, it also returns an identifier that you can use with `clearlInterval(...)` to stop things again. Having said that, if you only need things to trigger once, don't use `setInterval`. Just call your function, possibly as part of an event listener.

Comment: does the audio have a src property prior to you setting it in the interval ?

Comment: @Alex-TinLe sir the face-api should actually re-render itself after say every 1000ms in order to work so it needs constant re-rendering

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sir the face detection api requires constant re-running of the program hence i used setInterval method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it not to play while it is playing you could check and see if the audio is currently playing by checking the `paused` property in the conditional:

```
setInterval(async () => {
    //api stuff
    const detections = await faceapi
      .detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions());
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);
    const happy  =resizedDetections[0].expressions.happy;

    //The Issue  starts from here
    if(!audio.paused && happy>0.9)
    {
      audio.src="audios/happy_audio.wav";
      audio.play();
    }

    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections);
  },1000)
})
```

---

if you just want it to fire once use a flag:

```
let flag = false;

setInterval(async () => {
    //api stuff
    const detections = await faceapi
      .detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions());
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);
    const happy  =resizedDetections[0].expressions.happy;

    //The Issue  starts from here
    if(flag && happy>0.9)
    {
      audio.src="audios/happy_audio.wav";
      audio.play();
      flag = true;
    }

    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections);
  },1000)
})
```

**Note** I'm not a big fan of variable flags that are globally scoped. In the above case I would recommend a closure, or binding your asynchronous function to an Object that houses the flag, but as an example this should be sufficient :)

Answer (score 0):

As it was already said in comments, better is to move outside `setInterval` the code you want to run once.

But if you really want to keep it inside, then you can use a boolean variable which will allow to run only once.

Here is how:

```
let isFirstRun = true;

setInterval(async () => {
    //api stuff
    const detections = await faceapi
      .detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions());
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);
    const happy  =resizedDetections[0].expressions.happy;

    //The Issue  starts from here
    if(isFirstRun) {
        isFirstRun = false;

        if(happy>0.9)
        {
          audio.src="audios/happy_audio.wav";
          audio.play();
        }
    }
    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections);
  },1000)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it. So you want to stop the interval as soon as the happy index is > 0.9

```
let intervalID = setInterval(async () => {
    //api stuff
    const detections = await faceapi
      .detectAllFaces(video, new faceapi.TinyFaceDetectorOptions());
    const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(detections, displaySize);
    const happy  =resizedDetections[0].expressions.happy;

    //The Issue  starts from here
    if(!audio.paused && happy>0.9)
    {
      audio.src="audios/happy_audio.wav";
      audio.play();
      clearInterval(intervalID); // to stop next interval
      return; // to stop current interval
    }

    faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
    faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections);
  },1000)
})
```

Comment: sir the thing is that  i need to again resume the setInterval function let's say after the audio ends. also i need the other functions running in order get the proper video feed which freezes after the application of clearInterval() method.

Comment: I don't understand, so after break the interval loop. You want to start the loop again after the video ends. Then all you need to do is trigger the interval again when video ends. What the problem>?

Comment: sir i actually need that the audio should run independently , however if we stop the interval till the audio plays, the video feed is disrupted. so no changes in the fees will be encountered till then

Comment: Completely dont understand your problem. 